# Sheaf of isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory, module-isomorphism

Given $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}$, does the sheaf $Isom$ of isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, defined as

$$U\mapsto\mathrm{Sheaf}(U\mapsto \mathrm{Isom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X|U}}(\mathcal{M}|_U, \mathcal{N}|_U))$$

exist, where $\mathrm{Sheaf}$ is the sheafification functor? Is it a subsheaf of the sheaf Hom? Finally, do the operations for the sheaf Hom hold true for the sheaf Isom ?